# PowerBI: Getting count of customer that are

Tags: count, powerbi

I'm new to PowerBI. Please help me get the total count of recurring customers. I need to put the figure in a CARD.

Please see sample data.
The value that will be displayed on the card must be 3.
Customer R000563113 will not be included in the count since the customer is not on the prior month.

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S1b7.png)

Thanks

Comment: What if a customer belongs to January, February and March?

Comment: Then the customer count will be added for both February and March. Maybe I can just use a bar graph instead of a card and show from Jan-Dec. How can we do that?

Comment: You only have January to December data? I mean no year is there?

Comment: I have a slicer for year.

Comment: But, do you have checking like user from Jan,21 with Dec,20?

Comment: My basis for my date is transaction date only.

Answer (score 0):

just drag and drop your required column and in the card,

[image]

[image]

Comment: please see details again. I think what I put earlier is not clear.

Comment: do yo have slicer to select date range ?

Comment: Maybe I can just use a bar graph instead of a card and show from Jan-Dec. How can we do that?

Comment: yes, you can use bar graph and use months for x axis. Then you can add labels for that,